# SBT 0.13.7-RC2 hangs (windows)

Tags: sbt

We have a play2.3.4 codebase with lots of specs2 tests. When I switch to 0.13.7-RC2 the tests suddenly don't run, they just hang.

`sbt --debug` gives the following output and then just stops (with cpu activity < 1%)

```
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalatest.tools.Framework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework' not present.
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List((junit.framework.TestCase,false,com.novocode.junit.JUnit3Fingerprint@99d898d), (org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure,true,specs2 Specification fingerprint), (org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure,false,specs2 Specification fingerprint), (org.specs2.runner.FilesRunner,true,specs2 Specification files fingerprint), (org.specs2.runner.FilesRunner,false,specs2 Specification files fingerprint))
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List((org.junit.runner.RunWith,false,com.novocode.junit.RunWithFingerprint@4c7011c4), (org.junit.Test,false,com.novocode.junit.JUnitFingerprint@519e8210))
```

What is going on here? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I ran `jstack` to see whether a thread was hanging and there was a test dependency downloading a big file. The testplugin didn't report any activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `jstack` to see whether a thread was hanging and there was a test dependency downloading a big file. The testplugin didn't report any activity.

You can find the PID of the javaproces with `jps`.